# How to edit .py file inside google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a project entirely written in .py file. I want to edit something on that file so that I can customize my configuration of program

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%%writefile` or `%%file` to write and edit a small python file. Loading a file content into a cell doesn’t work yet though.